# Upload file using plupload in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5, plupload

I am using file upload in laravel 5.2. I am using AJAX to post the input data from the form. Now I am using plupload to upload the file. But now I am confused that what code should I write in controller to upload the file so that when I uploads the file using plupload file uploads in upload folder. So please suggest any solution.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files

Answer (score 1):

if you have something like this in ajax:

```
uploadUrl: "{{url('/uploadimage')}}",
```

and the form  have a hidden input.

```
 <input type="hidden" id="getimagename" name="uploadedimage" value="">
```

the controller  be like:

```
public function uploadimage()
{
    $target_dir = 'C:\xampp\..\';
    $tmpname = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
    $target_file= $target_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.basename($newfilename);
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $target_file)){
        echo json_encode($newfilename);die;
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(false);die;
    }
}
```